# two <div> layers with same properties in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way i put two layers in html ?
what i want to do is to put two  with same properties (size, place etc)
my purpose is when i hover the image (first div) the other div shows up (contains background image and text)

my actual code is :

```css
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 10%;   
    margin-top: 4%;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

 }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="column"> 
          <img src="images/Layer 3.png" style="width:100%" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">
          <img src="images/Layer 6.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 4.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 4.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 4.png" style="width:100%">
          </div> 
          <div class="column"> 
          <img src="images/Layer 6.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 12.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 4.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 7.png" style="width:100%">
          </div> 
          <div class="column"> 
          <img src="images/Layer 9.png" style="width:100%">
          <img src="images/Layer 8.png" style="width:100%">
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :hover element together with hiding.

```
element1:hover{
    display: none; 
} > element2{
    display: inline;
}
```

Add element1 to the first div's class and element2 to the second div!

Ps: sorry haven't tested, if it doesn't work I'm sorry but it is worth trying!